# Creating subdomain in virtualhost in apache 2.0 on CentOS 6.4

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, centos6

I need to create subdomains on a web server with **apache 2.0**, CentOS 6.4, PageSpeed ​​+ Apc.
I have no DNS server. I need to use VirtualHost.
My code:

```
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx     
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx>
    ServerName www.sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

I have put this code in: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/somename.conf` and it does not work.
Also in: `httpd.conf`, does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/storage/www/domain.com"
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias www.domain.com
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_domain.com_log combined
 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_domain.com_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like this

```
<Directory /var/www/xxxxx/data/www/domain.com>
    Options -Includes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data:."
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 155.155.255.152:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    CustomLog /dev/null combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/www/domain.com
    ErrorLog /dev/null
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    SuexecUserGroup xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/www/domain.com/cgi-bin/
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 155.155.255.152:443 >
    SSLCertificateFile /var/www/httpd-cert/xxxxxxxxx/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/httpd-cert/xxxxxxxxx/domain.key
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName domain.com
    CustomLog /dev/null combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/www/domain.com
    ErrorLog /dev/null
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    SuexecUserGroup xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/www/domain.com/cgi-bin/
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/xxxxxxxxx/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: loading domain perfectly. the problem is that you do to make a subdomain work.

for my tests I have edited my host local file:
xx.xx.xx.xx domain.com
xx.xx.xx.xx www.domain.com
xx.xx.xx.xx sub.domain.com
xx.xx.xx.xx www.sub.domain.com

I can not configure subdomains: (

Comment: Difficult for me to understand what you want I use the translator Can you not know where the settings?