# Creating auto subdomains?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, dns

I want to set up apache to create auto subdomains like so:

I have a domain `mysite.com`.
In my public `/www/` directory if I create a directory `/mysubdomain.mysite.com/` I want apache to create this subdomain so that I would be redirected to that directory, when trying to access this *URL*

Any tips please?

Comment: Have a look at this post you might get some help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843925/creating-subdomain-in-virtualhost-in-apache-2-0-on-centos-6-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualDocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) is likely what you want.  A configuration like this should take care of you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/%1"
    <Directory "/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need to make sure you either have a wildcard dns record for *.mysite.com or that every server name you want to use has an A record pointing at your Apache instance.

Comment: Many thanks! Got it working - I only had to change variable %0 to %1 and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, updated my answer to match.

Comment: Cool thanks, but I noticed that now if I try to access mysite.com I get 404... shall I update my question or make a new one?